# Angular 7 error:- error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: angular

I am getting this error I tried few solutions from stackoverflow but nothing worked for me
Solutions I have been tried

```
// Declare google ambient
declare var google: any;

package.json
"googlemaps": "^1.12.0"

tsconfig.json
 "types":[ "googlemaps"],
```

Stackoverflow questions

[Angular 6 - @types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364715/angular-6-types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module)

[error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'. Angular-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657819/error-ts2503-cannot-find-namespace-google-angular-7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed @types/googlemaps?
If not, try installing

```
npm i @types/googlemaps
```

Comment: Npm install is giving some issues in my project. So I manually imported it in node modules